# How do I add and remove a border on image in javascript

Tags: javascript

There is a problem in the onclick method, I want borders to be removed on all pictures except one when a new one is clicked

Error is: Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function
on line: images(i).style.display = "none";

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<title></title>
<script>
    var images = ['01.jpg', '02.jpg', '03.jpg', '04.jpg', '05.jpg', '06.jpg', '07.jpg', '08.jpg', '09.jpg', '10.jpg', 
                  '11.jpg', '12.jpg', '13.jpg', '14.jpg', '15.jpg', '16.jpg', '17.jpg', '18.jpg', '19.jpg', '20.jpg',
                  '21.jpg', '22.jpg', '23.jpg', '24.jpg', '25.jpg', '26.jpg', '27.jpg', '28.jpg', '29.jpg', '30.jpg',
                  '31.jpg', '32.jpg', '33.jpg', '34.jpg', '35.jpg', '36.jpg', '37.jpg', '38.jpg', '39.jpg', '40.jpg'];
    var end = 'cross.jpg';
    //to change index in array to display
    var first = 0;
    var last = 4;


    //sets border on image
    function setUpImage(i){

        var img = document.createElement('img')
        img.src = images[i];

        //adds image to screen
        document.getElementById('content').appendChild(img);

        img.onclick = function(){

            //if it doesnt have a border
            if(img.style.border != "10px solid blue"){

            //puts a blue border around image
            img.style.border = "10px solid blue";
            //add padding
            img.style.padding = "10px 10px 10px 10px";

            for(var i=0; i<=images.length; i++){
                images(i).style.display = "none";
            }

            }
        }
    }

</script>
<style>
#content{
width: 600px;
}
</style>
<body onload="buildImage();">
    <div id="content"></div>
       <button id="button" onclick="addImages()">More</button>

</body>
```

Comment: Arrays are indexed with `[]` and not `()`.  But once you fix that, you'll find that Strings don't have a style attribute... your images are just strings

Comment: Thank you! I was getting mixed up with passing into other methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your problem is that you did not actually select the img elements but rather the string in you images[] array, you will want to give your images an id so you can select them later, then iterate through them like you were, like this:

```
    //sets border on image
function setUpImage(i){

    var img = document.createElement('img')
    img.src = images[i];
    img.id = images[i];

    //adds image to screen
    document.getElementById('content').appendChild(img);

    img.onclick = function(){

        //if it doesnt have a border
        if(img.style.border != "10px solid blue"){

        for(var i=0; i<=images.length; i++){
            document.getElementById(image[i]).style.border = "initial";
        }

        //puts a blue border around image
        img.style.border = "10px solid blue";
        //add padding
        img.style.padding = "10px 10px 10px 10px";

        }
    }
}
```

I would however recomment only using one onclick function and giving this function to the onclick event for each image, like this:

```
    function imgClick(el){

        //if it doesnt have a border
        if(el.style.border != "10px solid blue"){

        for(var i=0; i<=images.length; i++){
            document.getElementById(image[i]).style.border = "initial";
        }

        //puts a blue border around image
        el.style.border = "10px solid blue";
        //add padding
        el.style.padding = "10px 10px 10px 10px";

        }
    }
```

and

```
//sets border on image
function setUpImage(i){

    var img = document.createElement('img')
    img.src = images[i];
img.id = images[i];

    //adds image to screen
    document.getElementById('content').appendChild(img);

    img.onclick = imgClick(this);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You make handy use of `querySelectorAll`, and CSS classes. In your CSS:

```
img.bordered { border: 1px solid black; }
```

And then you make use of this class in JavaScript via:

```
function clickHandler(evt) {
  var container = ... || document.body;
  var thisImage = evt.target;
  var allImages = topelement.querySelectorAll("img");
  // this is a NodeList, we want an array, so we convert:
  allImages = [].slice.call(allImages);
  allImages.forEach(function(img) {
    if(img===thisImage) 
      return img.classList.remove("bordered");
    img.classList.add("bordered");
  });
}
```

And then you bind that function either in HTML:

```
<img src="..." onclick="clickHandler">
```

Or in your JS when you create the elements:

```
...
var img = document.createElement("img");
img.addEventListener("click", clickHandler);
img.src = ...;
container.appendChild(img);
...
```

Done. All images are now given a CSS class that gives than a border, unless it's the image you clicked, in which case the border class gets removed instead. (If you remove a class that wasn't there, nothing happens, and if you add a class that was already there, also nothing happens).

Note that `container` var, which should be the element that houses all the images you want to toggle. Generally you wouldn't want to apply this to every possible image on a page, but only a specific set of images.